# How to run React Native in Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am a beginner using React Native, but I don't know how to run it in a browser, I tried searching in google but I didn't find anything, please give me a suggestion on how to run a react native in a browser.

Thanks.

Comment: try this https://medium.com/@jonnykalambay/your-first-hybrid-app-in-15-minutes-react-native-on-the-web-2cc2646051e

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by run it in a browser ?
If you mean display logs, yeah you can by activating the remote debug in your simulator.

But if you are talking about displaying your  UI in a browser, then NO.
react-native is to develop mobile apps, so to display your app you will need a simulator (android or ios depends on your laptop).

P.S: I advise you to you `Expo` it will be easier for you since you are a beginner

Answer (score 0):

You can not run react native apps in a browser ,But since I am guessing you have a smartphone ,you can build a React Native app
using Expo and you can test it in your phone.

Expo is actually recomended if you are a new developer on RN .

You sould use create-react-native-app to create your app and then after npm run just scan the QR code from your smartphone(you ll need to download expo there too) and voila!